# RPI 3 extremely slow routing speed between 2 wifi adapters

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi

I'm trying to use Raspberry Pi as a WiFi repeater, but routing speed is extremely slow. I've configured hostapd to work on wlan0 (onboard WiFi adapter) and wpa_supplicant on wlan1 (external adapter). Everything works fine except the speed. Home router provides internet about 80-90 Mbit/s, but connected devices receive only 5-15 Mbit/s.

The strange thing is that speedtest running on raspberry gives 80-90 Mbit/s.

What i've tried:

1. Different external adapters - did not help.
2. If i receive internet from ethernet cable i have about 40-50 Mbit/s, so seems that the onboard adapter is not a bottleneck.
3. If i run hostapd on external adapter and receive with onboard one - same problem.
4. I tried to run hostapd and wpa_supplicant on 2 external adapters - same problem.
5. I tried different distributives (raspbian, ubuntu)
6. I tried different boards (rpi b+, rpi b v1.2).
7. Tried to experiment with wifi bands (receive on channel 1, share on channel 11) - no result.
8. Tried to change device orientation (according to this answer [RPI wifi repeater - slow internet speed](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90247/rpi-wifi-repeater-slow-internet-speed))
9. CPU loading in all tests is about 10% *[Updated]*.

So seems that the problem is in forwarding soft inside the OS. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Low wifi speed even with 5Ghz wifi adapter](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105482/low-wifi-speed-even-with-5ghz-wifi-adapter). I seriously doubt you can get 80-90 Mbps on a Pi 3, AFAIK it's capped to around 36 Mbps even with a single adapter. And the load will be much higher than 1-2% for sure, especially if you do routing.

Comment: Incidentally, could you clarify what you mean by "forwarding"? I know about routing and network bridges, and forwarding is something you do on top of routing in case of NAT.

Comment: If I had a router that provided 80-90 m(illi)bit/s I would replace it with a piece of wet string.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I've checked wifi speed just now on builtin adapter - 80-90 mbit/s. CPU load is about 10%, made a mistake in the topic. By forwarding i meant routing between 2 wlan interfaces, my mistake.

Comment: How did you actually configure this passing of data from one wi-fi adapter to another?

Comment: `iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o wlan1 -j MASQUERADE`


Routing table is configured automatically with wpa_supplicant

Comment: Have you seen any similar project done before on a Pi? I am thinking that you have two wi-fi adapters and one core only. When you will check the speed on a specific wi-fi adapter, you will see the good speed, 80-100Mb/s. But when you will use two wi-fi adapters, it will move slower because that core will struggle to handle two interfaces. And the core usage will not necessarily go high because it's the interrupts which are slowing you down. Again, everything I am saying might be totally wrong. What do you think?

Comment: The strange thing is that transferring data between ethernet and wifi works pretty well (40-50 mbit/s). The problem exists only with 2 wifi adapters. And even when the hotspot is up and the clients are connected the speed on rasbperry itself is good, so seems that access point adapter does not affect receiving one.

Have you seen any similar project done before on a Pi? - No, i haven't.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128529/discussion-on-question-by-vlad-kudoyar-rpi-3-extremely-slow-routing-speed-betwee).

Comment: This should be closed as a duplicate.